# how to take input from user defined excel file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

hello guys..
              I am making a page in which i have to take excel file from user and read that file ..but all i know is to read a particular file by giving its address..for this i am using javascript and html ..here is my code for reading excel file

```
        <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="readdata(1, 2)" value="Submit" />

                <script>
            function readdata(x,y) {


       try {
        var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        excel.Visible = false;
        var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Test.xls");//                            
               alert(excel_file.worksheets.count);
        var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
        var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
        //alert(data);
        drawWithexcelValue(data);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
    //    return data;


     }
     </script>
```

This is my code for reading excel file by defining  path of a particular excel file...now i have to do is   take the excel file from user..guys please help..

And any kind of help through code wil be really appreciated..

someone please help me

Comment: As that an IE only solution you usually dont do it that way, rather upload the file to a server, process it there

Comment: i didn't get you ..could you please describe me via code

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex K mentioned, this would work only in IE.
Here a possible solution:

Put all of your Excel files in the same folder. For example: `C:\sheets\` 
(Edit: I think this is the easiest solution since I don't know of a way to get the full and real path of a file via javascript)

Now change your code to something along these lines:

```
<input type="file" id='excelFile' />
<button id='loadExcel'>Load Excel File</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var EXCELDIR = "C:\\sheets\\";
    var loadExcel = document.getElementById('loadExcel');
    loadExcel.onclick = function() {
        var filepath = EXCELDIR + document.getElementById('excelFile').value.split('\\')[2];
        readdata(1,2, filepath);
    }

    function readdata(x,y,filepath) {
       try {
        var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        excel.Visible = false;
        var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath);                       
               alert(excel_file.worksheets.count);
        var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
        var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
        //alert(data);
        drawWithexcelValue(data);
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
        //    return data;


    }
</script>
```

Disclaimer: I didn't check the code since I'm on mac, hopefully this works.

Comment: Thank you for your help SHIKAKA bro...but this code is not working man ..it is giving the error that D:\\file\\ could not be found

Comment: Can you write here exactly what you've put in `EXCELDIR`? and add the following after `var = filepath....`: `console.log(filepath)` and please tell me what you get in the console.

Comment: Thank you for reply Shikaka ..after adding console........still error is coming  Error.."could not  be found ...but something is strange it is not showing the name of the file.....its only saying that "could not be found..

Comment: write this at the beginning of the javascript: `console.log(document.getElementById('excelFile').value)` and tell me what it outputs

Comment: my manager is going to kill me ,if i am unable to send the code by this evening...:( ..Now you are my only hope bro